# Apache Beam: PTransform vs PValue

Tags: apache-beam, spring-cloud-dataflow

Given `PTransform<PCollection<X>, PCollection<Y>>` for arbitrary type X and Y. What exactly is transform and what exactly is PValue for this example? Is PValue defining a last vertex in a graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PValue` is a common base class for various things that can be inputs and outputs of a `PTransform`. `PCollection` is the most common example; other examples are: the trivial `PBegin` and `PDone`, `PCollectionTuple` (a transform can return multiple `PCollection`s - as `ParDo.withOutputTags` does), and it's possible to define custom `PValue`'s (though it's very rarely needed unless you're a library author), e.g. see [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/WriteFilesResult.java).